# How to implement HashLocationStrategy in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing, aspnetboilerplate

In aspnetboilerplate pages are coming correctly, when refreshed then also they are coming. The problem is when hosted, it is showing 404 error while refreshing the page why is it so? how can i implement HashLocationStrategy in it?

http://mywebsite.com/account/register when refreshing the page it is not coming it showing this error why is it so?

> 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`. There is nothing to do on the server for `HashLocationStrategy` to work. Perhaps you mean `PathLocationStrategy`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am using aspnetboilerplate template where do i want to give this

Comment: Sorry, I thought this is something server-side. Just look for `RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)` and add `{useHash: true}`.

Comment: i have checked the aspnetboilerplate demo but it works as expected http://eventcloud.aspnetboilerplate.com/Account/Register

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu it will work but when hosted will not i solved it

Comment: can you share your solution for the next comers

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu any idea about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795281/realtime-notification-in-aspnetboilerplate