# Realtime notification not sent

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to display realtime notification in ASP.NET Boilerplate, but it is not sent.

```cs
public override async Task<MessagesDto> Create(MessagesCreateDto input)
{
    var MessagesCore = ObjectMapper.Map<MessagesCore>(input);            
    MessagesCore.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(AbpSession.UserId);
    MessagesCore.CreationId = Convert.ToInt32(AbpSession.UserId);
    MessagesCore.FromUserId = Convert.ToInt32(AbpSession.UserId);
    MessagesCore.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
    MessagesCore.LastModificationId = Convert.ToInt32(AbpSession.UserId);
    MessagesCore.LastModificationTime = DateTime.Now;

    _stateRepository.Insert(MessagesCore);
    CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();

    UserIdentifier identifier = new UserIdentifier(1,input.ToUserId);
    await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(1, input.ToUserId), "NewMessage");
    await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("NewMessage", new SentMessageNotificationData("Test", "New Message"), userIds: new[] { identifier });

    return MapToEntityDto(MessagesCore);
}
```

`SentMessage` notification data class:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class SentMessageNotificationData : NotificationData
{
    public string SenderUserName { get; set; }

    public string FriendshipMessage { get; set; }

    public SentMessageNotificationData(string senderUserName, string friendshipMessage)
    {
        SenderUserName = senderUserName;
        FriendshipMessage = friendshipMessage;
    }
}
```

Data is stored in notification table, but no notification message is displaying in client side.

SignalR code in **app.component.ts**:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.appSession.application.features['SignalR']) {
    SignalRHelper.initSignalR();
  }

  abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', userNotification => {
    abp.notifications.showUiNotifyForUserNotification(userNotification);
    if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.LocalizableMessageNotificationData') {
        var localizedText = abp.localization.localize(
            userNotification.notification.data.message.name,
            userNotification.notification.data.message.sourceName
        );

        $.each(userNotification.notification.data.properties, function (key, value) {
            localizedText = localizedText.replace('{' + key + '}', value);
        });

        alert('New localized notification: ' + localizedText);
    } else if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.MessageNotificationData') {
        alert('New simple notification: ' + userNotification.notification.data.message);
    }
    //Desktop notification
    Push.create("AbpZeroTemplate", {
      body: userNotification.notification.data.message,
      icon: abp.appPath + 'assets/app-logo-small.png',
      timeout: 6000,
      onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am on netcoreapp2.0

- SignalR is still on `1.0.0-alpha2-final` for .NET Core.
- `2.x` will only be stable in Q1/Q2 2018.

## Update 1

[Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR) NuGet package has been published.

Read the documentation for [SignalR AspNetCore Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration).

You can [try](https://github.com/acjh/module-zero-core-template/blob/signalr-try/signalr-try.md) it and make the necessary [changes](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/compare/126dec8...a813437) to your files. <s>Or just wait for it to be released.</s>

## Update 2

You can now [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) `v3.4.1` of the template with the AspNetCore.SignalR preview.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create an event in client side to handle notification messages. You should set `abp.notifications.received` event like this;

```
abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function (userNotification) {
    console.log(userNotification);
});
```

You can find the more detailed explanation [here.](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#real-time-notifications)

**[Update]**

You need to integrate SignalR to get realtime notification works. Following the document [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the `Hub Class` in your Project?
You need to add a method there. SignalR Communicate mainly through `Hub` and send the realtime updates from `Client` Via **Hub** (Server) and from there to the destination i.e. where the realtime update is to be shown according to your Code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. If you see the record in database, then BackgroundJob might not be running to process the record. Put a debugger on background job to see if it traverses the record.

By the way, I see that you are passing 1 as tenant Id. So if you expect to get the notification from a tenant rather than default tenant, it'll never be delivered.

> UserIdentifier identifier = new UserIdentifier(1,input.ToUserId);